# Python: Convert list to a dictionary, where key is the index of the element of the list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `list` and I want to convert it to a dictionary `dict` where the key of an element is the position of the element in the list:

```
>>> list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> # I want the above list to be converted to a dict as shown below
...
>>> list_to_dict = {1: 'a',2: 'b', 3: 'c',4: 'd'}
```

I know it simple but and there are many ways as one in below:

```
>>> {index+1: item for index, item in enumerate(list_)}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

I can't understand totally how `collections.defaultdict` work, can we use it to achieve the above? Or maybe any other more efficient method?

Comment: What do you think is inefficient about the code you have? Why do you think that it needs to be any *more* efficient? Why do you think a `defaultdict` would help at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defaultdict()` produces default **values**, you are generating *keys* so it won't help you here.

Using `enumerate()` is the best way; you can simplify that to:

```
dict(enumerate(list_, 1))
```

The second argument to `enumerate()` is the *starting value*; setting it to 1 removes the need to increment the count yourself. `dict()` can consume the `(index, value)` pairs *directly*.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for removing the redundancy in my code!

Answer (score 1):

You could use defaultdict too.

```
from collections import defaultdict
list_ = ['a','b','c','d']
s = (zip([i for i in range(1, len(list_) + 1)], list_))
list_to_dict = defaultdict(str)

for k, v in s:
    list_to_dict[k] = v

print list_to_dict
```

or like below..

```
dict(zip([i for i in range(1, len(list_) + 1)], list_))
```

Comment: you are not actually using the default dict behaviour though, it would work the exact same if you did `list_to_dict = dict()`